# read file line by line in C(without using fgets)

Tags: c, file, operating-system, system-calls

I have a file with 3 lines in it, I'm tring to read this file and save each line as a separate string.
here is what I tried to do, it does save the first line but it overrides it by saving the first line and the second line' and I can't get my head around on how to do save each line as an individual string , and also I'm getting an error->

> *** stack smashing detected ***: /home/ubuntu/workspace/ex12.c.o terminated
>   Aborted

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include<stdio.h> 
 #include<fcntl.h> 
 #include<errno.h> 
 #include <unistd.h>
 extern int errno;                               
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
    char *path1;   
    char  firstline[80];
    char  secondline[80];
    char  thirdline[80];  

    printf("Program name %s\n", argv[0]);

    if( argc == 2 ) {
         printf("The path of the config file that you supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    else if( argc > 2 ) {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("One argument expected.\n");
    }

    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);  

    if (fd1 ==-1) 
    { 
        // print which type of error have in a code 
        printf("Error Number % d\n", errno);  

        // print program detail "Success or failure" 
        perror("Program"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }       
    else {            
        char c;
        int i=0;            

        while ((read(fd1, &c, 1) == 1) )
        {                
            firstline[i++]=c;                
            if(c=='\n')
            {
                //printf("end of line"); 
                printf("%s",firstline);
            }

        }
    }
    int close(int fd1);         
    return 0;        
}
```

NOTE: I DO NOT WANT to use fopen,fgets,sscanf or getline. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: First of all, it always pays to post well-formatted, nicely indented code. Nobody wants to read zigzags. Second, `int close(int fd1);` is a function prototype. It is not a function call and does not close any files. Third, you always read into `firstline`. Why do you expect it not to be overwritten? Finally, you do not reset `i` at the end of an iteration and run out of the array bounds.

Comment: E.g. you have to `break;` after the end of line 1 out of the while loop. In addition, there is no end of `i` , the firstline could be easily overflow!

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  and even after guessing as to which header file your actual code is including, there are still several warnings from the compiler about unused variables, etc.  Please fix the posted code so it cleanly compiles,

Comment: @Tom Kuschel  but if I break after the end of line 1 I won't be able to get line 2 and 3 which I want to get as 2 separate string like I did with line 1..

Comment: @ user3629249 I've added the header files, this should compile now

Comment: OT: when the incorrect number of command line arguments is supplied by the user.  Then output to `stderr`, a USAGE statement similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <configFileName>\n", argv[0] );`  followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are from the `stdlib.h` header file

Comment: @judy, not beautiful, but you could add a new while loop after the first while loop with the next string, and do not forget to add an `'\0'` to the end of the so buid string before breakiing. That was only an idea for your learning curve..

Comment: there is no need to include the same header file more than once.

Comment: @Tom Kuschel how can I start a new while loop from where the first loop stoped? won't it start from the top of the file?

Comment: I will give an example in an answer, just a second.

Comment: you do NOT want to be using the parameter: `O_CREAT` when all you want to do is read the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to demonstrate the brake from first loop from your example:

```
#define MAXLENGTH 80    
...

char  firstline[MAXLENGTH + 1] = {0};
char  secondline[MAXLENGTH + 1] = {0};
char  thirdline[MAXLENGTH + 1] = {0};  
....
else {            
    char c;
    int i=0;            
    while ((read(fd1, &c, 1) == 1 && i < MAXLENGTH)
    {                
        firstline[i++]=c;                
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            break; /* break from first loop */
        }
    }
    /* add a '\0' to the end of the string! */
    firstline[i] = '\0';
    //printf("end of line"); 
    printf("%s",firstline);
    i=0;            
    while ((read(fd1, &c, 1) == 1 && i < MAXLENGTH)
    {                
        secondline[i++]=c;                
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            break; /* break from second loop */
        }
    }
    /* add a '\0' to the end of the string! */
    secondline[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s",secondline);
    i = 0;
    int i=0;            
    while ((read(fd1, &c, 1) == 1 && i < MAXLENGTH)
    {                
        thirdline[i++]=c;                
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            break; /* break from third loop */
        }
    }
    /* add a '\0' to the end of the string! */
    thirdline[i] = '\0';
    //printf("end of line"); 
    printf("%s",thirdline);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` prints until a NULL terminating character is seen. Your printf goes over unallocated memory areas because you are not inserting a NULL(value 0) at the end of the string.
Also, you forgot to reinitialize i to 0.

```
while ((read(fd1, &c, 1) == 1) )
{                
    firstline[i++]=c;                
    if(c=='\n')
    {
        firstline[i] = 0;
        i = 0;
        //printf("end of line"); 
        printf("%s",firstline);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is most likely because you never reset `i` back to 0 so you keep reading more than 80 characters in to `firstline`

As to saving each line in to its own string, your just need to use you other variables, instead of using `firstline` all the time.

There a couple of ways to do that:

1. When you detect end of line exit the loop (with `break`), and start another loop where you will put the characters in `secondline`. Do the same for third.
2. If you already learned a bit about pointers, you can keep one loop, but use an extra variable, like `char *currentLine` that will hold the address of the array you want to read in to. Change the address every time you detect end of line like this: `currentLine = secondline`.

Also remember to put '\0' at the end of every line you read, or your program may print garbage when you try to print what you read to the screen.

Comment: you mean I should use break to exit the while loop? then how can I start a new while loop from where the first loop stoped?

Comment: You don't need to start from where the first one stopped, you need to start from the beginning - make sure `i` is zero and make sure you read in to a different array. When you `open` a file and read from it, the system keeps an internal pointer where to read from next. It does not matter where in your program you call `read` - it will always continue reading the file from where the last call to `read` stopped.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. proper checks for and handles errors
4. gives 'magic' numbers (3, 80) meaningful names

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINES 3
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 80


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  
{
    char Lines[ MAX_LINES ][ MAX_LINE_LEN ] = { '\0' };


    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <configFileName>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line arguments


    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY );  

    if (fd1 ==-1) 
    { 
        perror( "open failed" ); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }  

    // implied else, open successful        

    char c;

    for( int i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++ )
    {
        for( int j=0; j< MAX_LINE_LEN; j++ )
        {
            ssize_t bytecount = read(fd1, &c, 1 );
            if( bytecount < 0 )
            {
                perror( "read failed" );
                close( fd1 );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, read successful 

            Lines[ i ][ j ] = c;

            if( c == '\n' )
            {
                break;
            }   
        } 
    }

    for( int i = 0; i< MAX_LINES; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", Lines[i] );
    }

    close( fd1 );         
    return 0;        
}
```

Note: this code assumes that each line is less than 80 characters

running the proposed code against its' own source file results in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
```

Comment: could you please clarify why did you edit the code?(I currently compiled your previous code and going over it trying to understand it)

Comment: reasons for the edit: 1) `read()` does not stop at a newline so was reading way more than a single line 2)  I had suggested using `getline()`  Then I noticed that you did not want to use `getline()`.  Since `read()` does not stop due to a newline, I had to modify the code to read char by char and check each character for a newline